# Dynamic evaluation of a member without re-resolving the path leading to the member

Tags: c#, dynamic

Even though I usually prefer to ask a theoretical question and give an example later, I'll explain the situation with an example because I don't know where to start (the question is highlighted in bold):

Let's say I have an object (let's call him `FatOne`) that has a lot of properties, fields, mechanism, etc., from whom I want to get the following 'Linked' properties really often:

```
myFatOne.RootProperty1.OneLevelDeep1.TwoLevelDeepA;
myFatOne.RootProperty1.OneLevelDeep2.TwoLevelDeepB;
myFatOne.RootProperty2.OneLevelDeep;
```

But it happens that the costs of evaluating `OneLevelDeep2` and `RootProperty2` are really heavy. For the benefit of the question, I can't cache them. I want to create a lighter object (called `LiteOne` of course) that would contains the following members (note that I used 'members' and not method, field or property, because that' what the question is about.)

```
myLiteOne.Member1 (refers directly to 'myFatOne.RootProperty1.OneLevelDeep1.TwoLevelDeepA')
myLiteOne.Member2 (refers directly to 'myFatOne.RootProperty1.OneLevelDeep2.TwoLevelDeepB')
myLiteOne.Member3 (refers directly to 'myFatOne.RootProperty2.OneLevelDeep')
```

Of course, when I call `myLiteOne.Member1`, I don't want a cached value, **I want the evaluation of the last level** (i.e.: `TwoLevelDeepA` for `Member1`) **without having to resolve the whole 'chain'** (i.e.: `RootProperty1.OneLevelDeep1` for `Member1`), **how can I do that?** 
(I have the feeling it's something really simple and that I'm just having a brain fart right now.)

Idea 1, play with the Pointers. I'm not sure I want to go unsafe-style for that, I'm sure there is a better solution.

Idea 2, have fun with Func(). For example, if `Member1` is a Func, I could do this :

```
var tmp = myFatOne.RootProperty1.OneLevelDeep1;
myLiteOne.Member1 = new Func<T>(() => tmp.TwoLevelDeepA);
```

If I need `Member1` to be a property, I can just create an *underlying method* (instead of field) called `_member1` and wrap it with the `Member1` property.

Idea 3, have underlying fields on `LiteOne`. `LiteOne` could have 3 underlying fields of type `typeof(myFatOne.RootProperty1.OneLevelDeep1)`, `typeof(myFatOne.RootProperty1.OneLevelDeep2)` and `typeof(myFatOne.RootProperty2)` wrapped with the `Member1`, `Member2` and `Member3` properties that would get the `TwoLevelDeepA`, `TwoLevelDeepB` and `OneLevelDeep` members respectively. I think this would cause a problem however if one of the underlying field is a non-mutable though.

Any other (better) ideas?

Comment: So you don't want to cache the values and you don't even want to calculate them?
How do you think could using a Pointer, Func or PropertyInfo etc. reduce the costs? If you don't cache the values they need to be evaluated anyway.

Comment: You could use DynamicMethod to generate property get methods and use/cache these to access the target properties. Using DynamicMethod required IL knowledge unless you use a library like Fasterflect - see  http://fasterflect.codeplex.com PS: You'll probably need to cache a list of delegates (dynamic methods) to access the deeply nested properties.